# burn a iso image to a DVD+R and not DVD-R

Tags: dvd, burning, iso-image

I have a iso image of a movie, which was ripped from a DVD-R. I wana try to burn those images to a DVD+R but if fails.

What free software, or which is the best non-free software which can burn a DVD-R ISO image to a DVD+R?

Comment: is there an error message given?  DVD-R is *very slightly* bigger than DVD+R, and you may need to *shrink* the movie on that ISO in order to burn to DVD+R.

Answer (score 3):

The best software for that is [**ImgBurn**](http://www.imgburn.com/). If you still get errors with ImgBurn, there are other things to try. First, you need to make sure that your ISO image is not corrupted. You can mount your ISO to a virtual optical drive and check if it works. Then you can update the firmware of your DVD writer. It does not matter to rip from DVD-R or DVD+R. They can all be converted to ISO and recorded to any type of DVD media as long as the media size is sufficient.

Comment: Please note @quack quixote's comment. I've been bit by trying to burn DVD-R sized iso's to a DVD+R disc, even though the difference is like 6-7~ MiB.

Answer (score 1):

Like Mepher C. Palavuzlar said, ImgBurn is a great option. I just want to add that not all dvd players can play DVD+R dvd's. DVD-R is much more widely supported. You might be able to find more information about your dvd player online.

Some more details would be nice. The software you are currently using to burn the image and the error message would be useful. If there is no error message, describe the symptoms.